# Can't dup NilClass on association methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using rails 2.3.5 and ruby 1.8.7. I'm building a  simple TODO manager. Where I have tasks that belong to a user and a user has many tasks.

I'm using `acts_as_taggable_on_steroids` plugin for tagging tasks and `restful_authentication plugin` for registration and user management.

I'm getting a weird error that reads "Can't dup NilClass" on the view of index action. This is what the controller code is -

```
@tasks = current_user.tasks
```

The error occurs when I'm iterating over `@tasks` on the view. That is when I do `@tasks.each do |task|`

Now when I replace the controller code with this

```
@tasks = Task.find(:all, :conditions => {:user_id => current_user.id})
```

Which is actually fetching the same records. This happen only in development mode. I am guessing this has something to do with caching or loading.

What could be wrong? I'm facing this issue for the first time.

**EDIT**

Okay, this is definitely a caching issue. If I make
`config.cache_classes = true` in production.rb, the same error occurs in production mode as well. But how do I fix that now? Because I don't want to be reloading the server for every change I make in models/controllers.

**EDIT**

Here is how my User model looks like

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tasks
  has_many :projects

  # There are some validations and standard methods that resful authentication 
  # provides that I am not showing here

end
```

And this is how the Task model looks like.

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :bin
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :user

  acts_as_taggable

  def tag_list
    super.join(', ')
  end

end
```

Task controller's index method looks like this

```
def index
  @tasks = current_user.tasks

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.xml  { render :xml => @tasks }
  end
end
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got it.

From [here](http://strd6.com/?p=250),

> Some of the classes inherited or
>   included in your engine controllers
>   may fail to get unloaded and cause
>   trouble after the first request to
>   your system.

For me, it was because I had a file in the `lib` that was monkey patching User model and the 
User model class in this file was not getting cached I suppose.

Calling `unloadable` in that class in the lib folder did the trick. So my lib file looks like this

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  unloadable
  # stuff...
end
```

Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is something wrong with associations in model. Can you paste some code from there?

You can also try doing the same in console. Does it give the same error? Take a look in logs, do both of your examples generates the same sql query?

Comment: There is nothing wrong in the associations. Because the page works for the first time when I restart the server. Only when I try to load the page again without restarting the server, the error pops up. This is definitely a class caching issue.

Comment: If you would paste some model code and controller, maybe someone will see what is wrong. It's really hard to guess what is wrong only with informations you gave.