# can't dup NilClass - Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dup

I am stuck in this error for quite sometime now and have hit a dead end.

I get this totally unhelpful error

```
can't dup NilClass
```

This is the situation.

I have one class which is in a relationship with another. Say

```
 class Parent
 end

 class Child < Parent
    unloadable
     :has_many :parents, :foreign_key => "child"
 end
```

The error does not occur the first time it is accessed. It occurs the second time the child is accessed.

What is exactly causing this error and is there a solution?

I referred the [following link](http://strd6.com/2009/04/cant-dup-nilclass-maybe-try-unloadable/) but it doesn't  help

**Update**

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265145/cant-dup-nilclass-on-association-methods)

But it suggests the same again. But i do have a module in my lib. It Has nothing to do with the model though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you marking the Child as unloadable? Is there a good reason for this? if not, I'd remove.

[Rails API](http://as.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#M000013) says "Unloadable constants are removed each time dependencies are cleared."

Does the error happen when you change it to:

```
class Child < Parent
  has_many :parents, :foreign_key => "child"
end
```

And, I may be overstepping, but this seems more standard:

```
class Child
  belongs_to :parent
end

class Parent
  has_many :children, :dependent=>:destroy
end
```

Comment: but http://rails.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html says not to use :destroy when using :has_many.?

Comment: I believe it means don't have "belongs_to :parent, :dependent=>:destroy" -- in that case, if a parent has 4 children, and you destroy a child, then the child and the parent would be destroyed, but the other 3 child remain orphans.

Answer (score 0):

this is an error from the underground infrastructure. it may caused by very basic grammar error or so .

so I suggest you make sure all the config files are present(especially the config folder, those yaml files )

In my case, I solved this issue by adding the config/application.yml (which is a config file)